# Como formatar eixos em gráfico no visual studio

Tags: .net, vb.net

Gente, to tentando montar um gráfico de payback, mas está muito estranho.
Eu usei o seguinte código (resumo do que influencia):

```
Public vetor_x(121) As Integer

Public vetor_y(121) As Double 

Private Sub grafico_payback()

        For i = 0 To 120 Step 1

            vetor_x(i) = i

            vetor_y(i) = - investimento + (economia mensal * i)

        Next

    End Sub
```

A ideia é: no mês zero, não há economia, só o investimento (negativo). A partir do mês 1, esse gasto vai se diminuindo à medida que a economia (positiva) é creditada mês a mês, mas como vocês podem ver na foto, nao deu muito certo.

**Preciso ajustar esses valores do eixo X (para que vá de 0 - 120) e entender porque o programa plotou duas retas (a de baixo está certa, payback em aproximadamente 39 meses)**

Aproveitando, se alguem também souber como enfatizar a linha horizontal "y=0" e formatar os valores de "y" para aparecer em "R$ #.###,00", também agradeco muito
Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Leo, recomendo postar seu código inteiro para nos dar um contexto do que já foi realizado. Aproveitando, é VB.NET, certo?

Comment: Desculpe, sou bem amador, mas também não consigo colar o código inteiro por exceder o número de caracteres, como faço?    ps: sim, é VB.NET Framework